# Can't create virtual env with Python 3.9 in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, python-venv

I have installed both Python 3.7 and 3.9 in my Windows 10 using Microsoft Store, which put both python files in `\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`:

[image]

The problem is that, when I try to create a virtual env with Python 3.9 using `python3.9 -m venv venv`, I get this error:

```
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'
```

I read that this happens because it is trying to use *pip3.7*, but I can't find how to instruct python to use *pip3.9*.

Comment: Thinking out of the box: would this be more efficient if you were using a env manager where you can specify the Python version within the env (e.g. anaconda)?

Comment: Well, I don't know, If you give me a procedure to do so, I can evaluate it. I the end, what I want is to be able to create a virtual environment with Python 3.9

Comment: What are the contents of your $PATH and $PYTHONPATH env vars?

Comment: `path=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

Comment: `PYHTONPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python37.zip; C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs; C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib; C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset the $PYTHONPATH environment variable. That is what is causing python3.9 to incorrectly find code inside Python-3.7.

```
set PYTHONPATH=
python3.9 -m venv .venv
```